# Help with SQL Query -- Need Field with Highest Sum

Tags: sql

I have a table called NET_REPORT with the following fields (among many):

```
JOBS     – a number (of jobs)
NET_DATE – date in format YYYY-MM-DD
CODE     – a three digit integer (i.e., 001, 002, etc).
```

There can be multiple records for a single NET_DATE, each with a different code.
I need to know the maximum number of jobs in a single NET_DATE, over all codes.

I had the query `SELECT MAX(JOBS) as MaximumJobs FROM NET_REPORT`, but this gives me the maximum jobs for a particular NET_DATE and CODE.  Instead, I need to add together the value in the JOBS field for all the records for each NET_DATE, then find the maximum value of all those totals.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Version**

```
SELECT sum(JOBS) as JobCount, NET_DATE FROM NET_REPORT GROUP BY NET_DATE
```

**If you want to order by NET_DATE, starting with the highest Job Count**

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT sum(JOBS) as JobCount, NET_DATE FROM NET_REPORT GROUP BY NET_DATE) AS A
ORDER BY A.JobCount DESC
```

**If you need only the NET_DATE with the highest Job Count**

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM
  (SELECT sum(JOBS) as JobCount, NET_DATE FROM NET_REPORT GROUP BY NET_DATE) AS A
ORDER BY A.JobCount DESC
```

## References

- [Group By Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
- [TSQL Sub Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that worked well, with the insertion of DESC at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(JobsTotal) as MaximumJobs
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(JOBS) AS JobsTotal
    FROM NET_REPORT
    GROUP BY NET_DATE
) A
```

Comment: That looks great, but when I try to put it all into a sqlcmd statement, I get a syntax error.  The statement is: 
sqlcmd -S ctmdemo01\CTMEM -d EM640 -U emuser -P empass -Q "SELECT MAX(JobsTotal) as MaximumJobs FROM ( SELECT SUM(JOBS) AS JobsTotal FROM NET_REPORT GROUP BY NET_DATE)"  
Syntax error is "Incorrect syntax near .(."

Comment: In fact, I get the same error when I do it using interactive SQL.

Comment: @Rachel and Gavin: An alias must be provided for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is count of distinct jobs for the "how many jobs" on a given date.  With respect to your count and summation, I've added those too, just keep the single "group by" of the net_date.

```
select 
      net_date,
      count( distinct jobs ) as NumberOfJobs,
      sum( jobs ) as SumOfJobs,
      max( jobs ) as MaxJobs
   from
      net_report
   group by
      net_date
```

If you are looking for the date that has the MOST unique jobs going on, then add the following to the above query

```
  order by 2 DESC limit 1
```

The order by 2 refers to the ordinal column "NumberOfJobs", Limit 1 to return only the first entry of the final "ordered" result set.